# Which is faster - Conditional String Formatting or Conventional if/else?

Tags: python, performance, string-formatting, processing-efficiency

> Method 1 - Conventional `if/else`:

```
from collections import Counter

sentence = Counter(input("What would you like to say? ").lower())
sentence_length = 0

for k, v in sentence.items():
    if v > 1:
        print("There are {} {}'s in this sentence.".format(v, k))
    else:
        print("There is {} {} in this sentence.".format(v, k))
    sentence_length += v

print("There are {} words, including spaces, in total.".format(sentence_length))
```

> Method 2 - Conditional String Formatting:

```
from collections import Counter

sentence = Counter(input("What would you like to say? ").lower())
sentence_length = 0

for k, v in sentence.items():
    print("There {} {} {}{} in this sentence.".format(("are" if v > 1 else "is"), v, k, ("'s" if v > 1 else "")))
    sentence_length += v

print("There are {} words, including spaces, in total.".format(sentence_length))
```

Both code snippets are used to calculate the number of occurrences of a particular character in a sentence. The difference between the two methods is the part inside of the "for" statement - Conditional String Formatting or Conventional if/else. I am trying to figure which method would be more efficient.

Comment: The performance difference is almost certainly going to be so tiny it doesn't matter compared to the rest of what your program is doing. But if you really need to know, measure it with the `timeit` module, or the `%timeit` magic command in IPython/Jupyter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's no algorithmic difference between the two, the only way to answer this question is to test it.

Of course it's hard to benchmark a program that includes an `input`, so first I timed how long it took me to type my desired sentence, then I replaced that with a constant assignment and a `time.sleep(7.8)`.

Both versions took well under 8 seconds. And most of the time outside the 7.8 seconds was spent in `print`.

But, according to `%timeit`, version 1 was about 0.0005 seconds faster than version 2, for a speedup of about 0.006%.

(By the way, you get more speedup than that changing from `str.format` to `%`.)

I'm pretty sure almost all of the difference comes down to having more parameters to `str.format`, not to the difference between `if` statements and `if` expressions.

But of course the details probably depend on your chosen Python implementation, and maybe your version and platform, and on what input string you give it, and, more than anything else, how fast you can type. So, if this 0.006% difference actually matters for something, you really need to test it yourself.